# open api 3 add multiple random examples for a single string item

Tags: openapi

I have a `text.yaml` - a single string item.
I want it to pass random string examples to my documentation to represent real life cases.

```
type: string
example:
  - Example Text
  - טקסט לדוגמא
  - 123 text with numbers 456
description: localized text to show
```

tried with `examples` but it's not supported.

this doc - https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/adding-examples/ does not list any valid parameters for this